# Sorting CSV file based on scores

Tags: python

I cannot figure out how to print and sort my csv file which involves the scores, names, and times of players in my game so I can print the top 5 scores.

Iv been looking through stackoverflow for a while and cannot find anything which matches to the specifications I require or fits what I need. So if someone could help that would be awesome.

My csv file looks as follows:

```
Human,02:00,120
Joe,03:00,180
Alex,01:00,60
Jason,05:00,300
Liza,06:00,360
John,07:00,420
Mark,04:00,240
```

The file columns are: `Name, Time, RawTime. The RawTime` column is what I would want to sort in order to list the lowest to highest times within the top 5

```py
def addtoScoreboard(name, time, scores):
    file = open("scores.csv", "a")
    file.write("\n" + str(name) + "," + str(time) + "," + str(scores))
    file.close
```

This is how I'm adding my scores to the text file.

It would be really cool if someone could aid me in order to sort and print the data within my csv file which I can later add to my game.

Comment: You could look into the `csv` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) which will let you read your file in like a list and then you can just sort that list and recreate your csv file.

Comment: You should add parentheses to you call to `file.close`. So it looks like `file.close()`.

Comment: Doesnt change anything

Comment: You can read your csv into a list of dictionary, and then sort that list! Check my answer below @KallumHancox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
import csv

li = []
#Import the csv as a dictionary
with open("out.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)

    #Append all items to a list
    for item in reader:
        li.append(dict(item))

#Sort the list on Rawtime key
res = sorted(li, key=lambda x:int(x['RawTime']), reverse=True)

#Remove Rawtime from result
res = [ {i:item[i] for i in item if i!='RawTime'} for item in res[:5]]
print(res)

#Print without Name and List
for item in res:
    print(','.join(list(item.values())))

#Write to a csv
keys = ['Name', 'Time']
with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, keys)
    #Write the header
    writer.writeheader()
    #Write the keys
    for item in res:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

So if the csv looks like

```
Name,Time,RawTime
Human,02:00,120
Joe,03:00,180
Alex,01:00,60
Jason,05:00,300
Liza,06:00,360
John,07:00,420
Mark,04:00,240
```

The output will be

```
[{'Name': 'John', 'Time': '07:00'}, 
{'Name': 'Liza', 'Time': '06:00'}, 
{'Name': 'Jason', 'Time': '05:00'}, 
{'Name': 'Mark', 'Time': '04:00'}, 
{'Name': 'Joe', 'Time': '03:00'}]
```

And the output csv will look like

```
Name,Time
John,07:00
Liza,06:00
Jason,05:00
Mark,04:00
Joe,03:00
```

Printing without name and list looks like

```
John,07:00
Liza,06:00
Jason,05:00
Mark,04:00
Joe,03:00
```

Comment: how would i make it so when printed rawTime isnt displayed as thats just for sorting purposes

Comment: Yeah so rawtime isnt printed only used to sort the data

Comment: Let me change my answer!

Comment: Done! Please check, `RawTime` is removed from the dictionary!

Comment: Works perfectly. Last question just to be awkward. Is there anyway to remove the colum titles from each bit of data output so it doesnt say eg. "Name: Liza" but instead just "Liza"

Comment: Sure this is just dictionary output, When you write it to a CSV, all this will go away, let me add writing to CSV part as well! Meanwhile, if the answer helped you, please upvote and accept

Comment: Updated how to write to output csv, and how does output csv look like!

Comment: Why do you need to write back to the file and not just print without the colum titles? Is is not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, Let me add that too!

Comment: Updated! please check!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `csv` module. And using `sorted()` with `key` to sort by time.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename, "rU") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    data = [row for row in reader]
    data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]))   #Sort by RawTime

with open(filename_1, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

**Output:**

```
Alex,01:00,60
Human,02:00,120
Joe,03:00,180
Mark,04:00,240
Jason,05:00,300
Liza,06:00,360
John,07:00,420
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library, that, although being a bit overkill, allows you to write more concise code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', names=["Name", "Time", "RawTime"])
df = df.sort_values('RawTime')
df.to_csv('scores.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_arr = []
with open("your_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        name, time, raw_time = line.split(",")
        data_arr.append((name, time, int(raw_time)))

    data_arr = sorted(data_arr, key= lambda x: x[2])

with open("output_file.txt", "w") as f:
    output = ""
    for name, time, raw_time in data_arr:
        output += (name + "," + time + "," + str(raw_time)) + "\n"
    f.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas for same

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv',header=None)

(df.sort_values([2],ascending=False) ## sorting high to low on column 2
 .head(5) ## taking top 5
 .sort_values([2],ascending=True) ## sorting low to high
 .to_csv('scores.csv',header = False,index=False)) # exporting as csv
```